# Counting divs on a page every 3 seconds

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to check how many of a certain item are being dropped on this website. I am using beautiful soup to check the amount of divs. When I run my code, it just repeats the same value and never goes up even when more items are being dropped. Here is my code:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://g2case.com/en"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

running = True

while running:

    for i in range(5):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
        milspecs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item milspec"})
        print(len(milspecs))
        time.sleep(3)

    running = False

print "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually *fetch* the new page with another call to `browser.get(url)` inside of your loop. As it is, you only get the page once and parse the same page over and over again. This way, you fetch the current verison of the page each time through the loop.

```
while running:

    for i in range(5):
        # Be sure to actually fetch the new data
        browser.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
        milspecs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item milspec"})
        print(len(milspecs))
        time.sleep(3)

    running = False
```

As a sidenote, it is definitely not recommended to continuously poll someone else's website with a script like this. If you can, try to find a public API that will give you access to the data underlying the website without scraping it every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying you should make constant requests to some website that might not like it but if you want to update your local version of the site every 3 seconds, you'll also have to fetch it every 3 seconds. Move `browser.get(url)` into the loop like so:

```
...
while running:
    browser.get(url)
    for i in range(5):
    ...
```